# ERROR (java.sql.SQLException)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

i am tryin to use  sqlite-jdbc in android but give me error when trying to connect to database. below my code .

```
   Class .forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:category1.db");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );

    }
    Log.w(TAG,"#######{}{}{}{}{*Opened database successfully");
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
```

this the error when run app.

W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: opening db: 'category1.db': open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: Where is `category1.db` located on your device?

Comment: @MichaelDodd    i  am not specified it it will create  automatic   when not found

Comment: If the database not created within your app's sandbox using `getFilesDir()` or similar storage-related methods, then your app will not have write access.

Comment: @MichaelDodd  can you give me  more details or example how to do it   i am not have  experience

Comment: It depends. Can you post the bit of code where you're defining where `category1.db` is created?

Comment: @MichaelDodd    i  only test connection  i need to create  category1.db in my mobile app  till now i not wirte  acode